# Loop with jquery on mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my project, The costumers can do discount to their products for a while. When That while finishs, Discount finishs. Every second or minute, The Program must control the discount finish dates. But If I want to do that, I have to reload the page again everytime. So How can i do that with js on mvc ?

Answer (score 1):

You use ajax calls from your front end and JsonResult return types in your controllers. Here is a tutorial to get you going: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/jsonresult-type-in-mvc/